# AWS Lambda: How to manage deployment packages greater than 250mb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have some image processing code in Python3.6 that I am trying to deploy to AWS Lambda using AWS SAM. The total size of all dependencies (pip packages) is greater than 250mb. I've already broken down the function into smaller parts but they all end up using the same packages, so that did not help in reducing the size.

I am using the following packages:

```
opencv-python
numpy
joblib
imutils
mahotas
scikit-image
scikit-learn==0.22.1
sklearn
```

Cold start is not an issue in my use case so I don't mind that. What possible options do I have? The requirement is to run this on Lambda.

Comment: How much bigger than 250MB are they all? And are you using and particular deployment tools; SAM or sls?

Comment: It's about 340mb. Yes, I am using SAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS very recently released EFS support for Lambda. You should be able to put your dependencies there. There are some examples in this blog post: [Using Amazon EFS for AWS Lambda in your serverless applications](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/).

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue. But in my use case, my Lambda can not be a part of any VPC and has to be open to the internet without using NAT Gateway and all that. If your use case is to use Lambda with in a VPC, this is a great solution. If not; you can try serverless framework's `zip`, `slim` & `strip` options to try and get the package to a more manageable size.